# Storing git like commit history of changes

Tags: postgresql, neo4j

I want to build a git like versioning system for one my database entities.

The models would be:

```
Commit
  parent_commit_id

Change
  entity_id
  commit_id
  modifier (added, deleted, modified)

Entity
```

An Entity is never really deleted so an user can undo a commit and end up with a valid state.

It sounds simple, but:

- A commit is generated on every click by the user (performance is very important)
- On every commit there will be about 100 changes (either modifications, additions or deletions)

Because we are just storing changes, the current state must either be calculated or stored.

**Option 1**: Saving the complete state for every commit would mean that I would not only store the modifications, additions and deletions in a commit, but also every entity that has not changed. I think this is not an really an option because there will be more than 20 million entities when the system is running.

**Option 2**: Calculating the current state by using a recursive common table expression. I don't know if this is fast enough...

**Option 3**: Performing a clean up after a certain period of time (like git gc). This would mean that I would actually delete all entities that are no longer valid at the time of the clean up. Not really an option because I want to be able to see all changes and go back to those changes.

**Option 4**: Use a graph database (neo4j)? Could it handle such a specifaction with reasonable performance?

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I'd want to store two things - an `unlogged` table with the current state, and an ordinary table containing a series of changes and the original state. On crash, you can regenerate the unlogged "current state" table by applying the history diffs, though it'll take a while. (Depending on consistency requirements, you may even choose to use something like redis / memcached to store the current state. But you need to cache it somehow.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of using Neo4j is an interesting one. A quick read of http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Internal_structure already shows the level of complexity in git as well as the fact that the Topology of Commits is a 'Directed Acyclic Graph', which speaks in favor of Neo4j.

But one thing to consider is just how complex a model you are planning? Do you want some or all of the complexity of git? If so a flexible database like Neo4j would be a good idea.

If you only want something that tracks changes to single files, without concern for multiple concurrent users, then consider the old RCS system, which stored the latest file, plus a chain of diffs to previous revisions. This could just as easily be stored in two tables (one for files, and one for changes). It is the opposite direction of Dan's answer, which stores the first file and the changes from there. Both ways work, but the RCS way will be able to retrieve recent versions faster than older versions, while the video approach retrieves the older versions fastest. Since you watch video from oldest to newest, it makes sense they did it that way, but I think for file revisions you usually want the newest first. For a more thorough review of these kinds of approaches, check out Martin Fowlers blog on [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). These approaches, however, do not really consider multiple concurrent users, or anything complex at all. But they could be the foundation for more.

So let's reconsider the more complex model. Neo4j is schema-less, allowing you to start simple and enhance with features as you need. For example, you might follow this route:

- Build a simple RCS-like file revision system, with the latest contents in a single graph node, and a chain of links to older versions (or chain of diffs to older versions)
- Then you decide you need to support commits of multiple files, you add the tree objects (described at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Internal_structure), and these can be real tree structures in the graph, with graph nodes linked to the file object nodes.
- These trees are referenced by commit objects, which themselves are linked in chains, with previous commits. Once you have these commit chains, you may not need the file chains anymore, because you would traverse the commit chains instead. Each commit points to a tree, which points to the files.
- Then perhaps you decide to support branching, and so you add tag and branch objects, which link to the commits (and from there trees and files). This leads naturally to the acyclic directed graphs that show the branching and merging that occurs over time.
- And then perhaps you even consider adding the reflogs, which could also be modeled as a graph.

As you work through the list above, the total graph gets richer and more complex, supporting a larger set of use cases. I think this is a nice way to build a data model.

One thing that is clear from reading http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Internal_structure is that even with the simplified description provided there, we can already see a lot of value in modeling most of is a graphs. Linked lists, trees and acyclic directed graphs. Sounds to me like Neo4j would be a nice technology to do this with.

So how to get started? Take a look, for example, at some of the [Graph Gist Examples](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/wiki). One simple one that seems relevant here is the [Simple versioning nodes scheme](http://gist.neo4j.org/?6628418). And then build from there.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the links to the graph gists. I think I'll give Neo4j a try.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to think through some of the details - but what if you took a lesson from video processing - have the original checkin, and have each version have the delta, but have a 'keyframe' property that would indicate a full snapshot, every, say 10 commits, and always the latest version.  Give you a mix of good performance w/o storing full data for each commit...